# NSNotification not being called on super

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a class I do something like the following:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(windowWillClose:) 
                                                 name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification 
                                               object:self.window];
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"closing");
}
```

**Then I subclass this class**.  There's only one problem.  When I subclass this class, the notification is never sent.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I assume that you are, in fact, showing this window controller's window and then closing it.

Comment: Well that's what I'm sort of doing.  I created a window manager that holds onto a retained instance of the window, then I'm trying to intercept the close event in order to remove it from the array of windows in my window manager.

Comment: Please edit your question to show that code. The code you have in the question right now should work fine as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your subclass override `windowDidLoad` and/or `windowWillClose:`? If so, do your subclass's implementation(s) call `super`?

Comment: No, I do not override any of those methods.  The implementation is empty.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't retaining the window **controller**, only was I retaining the window.  Thanks for indirectly helping me find that.

Answer (score 1):

You may miss something, please check

1. Did you already override these method on your subclass?

   `- (void)windowDidLoad`

   `- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification`
2. If you did in 1. Did you write the code like this?

   `[super windowDidLoad];` or `[super windowWillClose:param];`

Comment: No, I do not override any of those methods. The implementation is empty.

Answer (score 0):

1)Add below line at windowDidLoad or awakeFromNib

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(windowWillClose:) name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:self.window];
```

2)Select the window and navigate to Attribute inspected and and check the "Release when Closed" check box.